# Does Monetdb support server-side scripting like PG/SQL?

Tags: database, postgresql, monetdb

Hi I read [Here](http://db-engines.com/en/system/MonetDB%3BOracle%3BSQLite) that MonetDB support server-side script (like PG/SQL for Oracle). However I'm not able to found any related documentation on the [MonetDB website](https://www.monetdb.org/)

Can some one have any pointers, documentation, tutorial about server-side scripting in monetdb ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the anwser in this web page [see here](https://www.monetdb.org/print/book/export/html/326)